# How to get an index of an element of a specific class

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I need to get an index of the item I clicked, but only an index of items with a specific class.

```
<div class="gallery">

   <div class="gallery-item"></div>
   <div class="gallery-item"></div>
   <div class="gallery-item select-gallery-item"></div> <!-- click on this -->
   <div class="gallery-item"></div>
   <div class="gallery-item"></div>
   <div class="gallery-item select-gallery-item"></div>
   <div class="gallery-item select-gallery-item"></div>
   <div class="gallery-item select-gallery-item"></div>

</div>
```

```
$('.gallery').on('click', '.select-gallery-item', function () {
   $(this).index();
};
```

For example, I click on this element with a class '.select-gallery-item', I will get an index - 2. But among the elements with the class '.select-gallery-item', its index - 0

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Call `index(this)` off of the selected elements the index should be based upon.

```js
$('.gallery').on('click', '.select-gallery-item', function () {
   console.log($('.select-gallery-item').index(this));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">

   <div class="gallery-item">a</div>
   <div class="gallery-item">b</div>
   <div class="gallery-item select-gallery-item">c</div> <!-- click on this -->
   <div class="gallery-item">d</div>
   <div class="gallery-item">e</div>
   <div class="gallery-item select-gallery-item">f</div>
   <div class="gallery-item select-gallery-item">g</div>
   <div class="gallery-item select-gallery-item">h</div>

</div>
```

Comment: also $('.gallery >.select-gallery-item').click(function () {
   console.log($(this).index('.select-gallery-item'));
}); will work?

Comment: @Supercool.  It will not work if the elements are dynamic, as suggested by the usage of a delegate event handler.

Comment: When we click, it console 0, 1 , 2 why? Could you please explain. I suppose we need to show index of the element that has class `select-gallery-item`

Comment: @Charu It logs `0, 1, 2` because the index is based off of the result stack of the previous lookup, which contains only the elements with the desired class.